# Problemas con parametros de url angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-router

estoy usando paramMap.get('') para obtener un token de la url y pasarselo a una funcion, el tema es que el token que quiero enviar es:

```
SQFEa%2B%2BWR0MhdeT8l0aFqRTHT95vVtqPdJq2dnnFLlzS7rHsq367Rc6w%2FT1HkDnJw3IAEuZBFelAS28DPzP9bdWNOp92pzUFnbiOyN0Zlqo%3D
```

y el que llega es:

```
SQFEa%2B%2BWR0MhdeT8l0aFqW3qCsyktBRUUc1NEsyJifyJuM4VuSszCxUQPRtgDzEdUWnCQ93ZH%2F%2Fo7d%2Fk5plJaSFvxj89MOitzi4Q6COIQiY%3D
```

como podria arreglar ese problema? he intentado usar (encodeURIComponent(this.urlData) pero no me ha funcionado, gracias!

Comment: cual es la diferencia que tienes entre los dos tokens, ya que los dos los veo yo como un url encode, solo son diferentes tokens.

Comment: Por la otra parte debes usar `decodeUriComponent`